# How to utilize the remainder theorem when the quotient is unknown?

Tags: polynomials

I encountered this question, and I am unsure how to answer it.

When $P(x)$ is divided by $x - 4$, the remainder is $13$, and when $P(x)$ is divided by $x + 3$, the remainder is $-1$. Find the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $x^2 -  x - 12$.

How would I proceed? Thank you in advance!

Comment: HINT: $x^2-x-12=(x-4)(x+3)$

Comment: I see. Is the answer 2x + 5 then?

Answer (score 1):

Use the inverse isomorphism of the isomorphism in the *Chinese remainder theorem*: as $x^2-x-12=(x+3)(x-4)$, we have  an isomorphism
\begin{align}
K[X]/(X^2-X-12)&\xrightarrow[\quad]\sim K[X]/(X+3)\times K[X]/(X-4) \\
P\bmod(X^2-X-12)&\longmapsto(P\bmod (X+3), P\bmod (X-4)&&(K\text{ is the base field})
\end{align}
and given a Bézout's relation $\;U(X)(X+3)+V(X)(X-4)=1$, the inverse isomorphisme is given by
$$(S\bmod (X+3), T\bmod(X-4))\longmapsto TU(X+3)+SV(X-4)\bmod(X^2\!-X-12) .$$

Now a Bézout's relation can be found with the *extended Euclidean algorithm*, but in the present case it is even shorter:$(X+3)-(X-4)=7$,  so we simply have
$$\frac17(X+3)-\frac17(X-4)=1$$
and given that $\:P\bmod(X+3)=-1$, $P\bmod(X-4)=13$, we obtain readily
$$P\bmod(X^2-X-12)=\frac{13}7(X+3)+\frac17(X-4)=2X+5.$$

Answer (score 0):

$P(x)=(x^2-x-12)Q(x)+ax+b$

$P(4)=4a+b=13$

$P(-3)=-3a+b=-1$

$a=2, b=5$

$P(x)=(x^2-x-12)Q(x)+2x+5$

$R(x)=2x+5$